# Hide gridlines in Google Docs spreadsheets by default?

Tags: google-sheets

I general like to hide spreadsheet gridlines. Google Docs has them on by default when you create a new sheet. Is there any way to have them hidden by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've searched the net and wasn't able to find a solution for you. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14566540/1536038) on SO, it's also not possible to do it via Google Apps Script.

Copying from a template, having no gridlines, is just as quick as deselecting the gridlines.